# Moengage issue when application is reopened

Tags: android, moengage

Application crashes when the app comes to the foreground.
When the application is killed and relaunched, it doesn't crash but when it is minimized and reopened, it crashes with the below exception

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.moengage.locationlibrary.LocationHandlerImpl
>                                                                    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                                    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
>                                                                    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:285)
>                                                                    at com.moengage.location.GeoManager.getHandler(GeoManager.java:33)
>                                                                    at com.moengage.core.MoEDispatcher.syncInAppsAndGeo(MoEDispatcher.java:209)
>                                                                    at com.moengage.core.MoEDispatcher.onStart(MoEDispatcher.java:159)
>                                                                    at com.moe.pushlibrary.MoEHelper.onNewIntent(MoEHelper.java:287)
>                                                                    at com.moe.pushlibrary.MoEHelper.onStartInternal(MoEHelper.java:324)
>                                                                    at com.moe.pushlibrary.MoEActivityLifeCycleCallBacks.onActivityStarted(MoEActivityLifeCycleCallBacks.java:33)
>                                                                    at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityStarted(Application.java:205)
>                                                                    at android.app.Activity.onStart(Activity.java:1146)
>                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542)
>                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
>                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
>                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 10-23
>   13:26:14.136 7406-7406/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7406 SIG: 9

I did try the solution for **NoClassDefFoundError** but it didn't work. I am confused about it running when relaunched but not when it comes to foreground from minimized status.

Following is my applicaiton Class:

```
public class AppController extends Application implements PushManager.OnTokenReceivedListener {
    MoEHelper helper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        helper = MoEHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        helper.autoIntegrate(this);
        PushManager.getInstance().setTokenObserver(this);

        Log.e("TAG", "onCreate() AppController");
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MoTest", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (pref.contains("newInstall")) {
            helper.setExistingUser(true);
        } else {
            helper.setExistingUser(false);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTokenReceived(String token) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Appcontroller Token: " + token);
    }
}
```

and this is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your **LocationHandlerImpl.java** file and see if *GoogleApiClient* and *LocationServices* are resolved. There is a possibility that you haven't added the dependency for the Location services.

If they are not resolved, add respective dependency to your Gradle file

> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:XXX'

Sync and try running it again. That should do the job

Answer (score 2):

The MoEngage SDK assumes that your application has the location services dependency if you have location permission, same is the case here. 
That being said the SDK provides a mechanism to exclude the location library in case you don't want to use our Geo-fencing feature. This can be done as follows:

```
compile ('com.moengage:moe-android-sdk:7.7.16') {
        exclude group: 'com.moengage', module: 'moe-location-lib'
    }
```

You can refer to official docs [here](https://docs.moengage.com/docs/optouts#section-opt-out-from-location-tracking-and-geofence) for more details.

PS: I am one of the contributing members of the MoEngage SDK. Let me know if this is not solved.